# Firebase setup - connect to multiple projects

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-remote-config, firebase-performance

We have a "white label" mobile app with plans to provide it to multiple customers.  We would like to rely on Firebase Crashlytics, Push Notifications, Analytics, In App Messaging, Remote Config, Performance Monitoring and other capabilities.  However, this functionality or rather access to some of these capabilities would have to be segregated from our customers.  As creators/owners/maintainers, we would like to keep control (and exclusive access) to Crashlytics, Remote Config or Performance Monitoring, among others, while configuring Push Notifications, Analytics, In App Messaging, etc. to be accessible and "owned" by the customer.  Is there a way to configure an app with multiple Firebase projects or accomplish the above described separation otherwise?  Preferably, there should be a hard separation (e.g. different Firebase projects) vs. a soft one (i.e. permissions within the same project).

Comment: Yes, you should use multiple projects, one for each app. What is the specific problem with doing that?

Comment: Look at this - Remote Config vs. Push Notifications or Analytics.  We would like to use Remote Config to enable/disable features, based on what the customers sign up for.  This config should not be accessible to the customers, under any circumstances.  Push Notifications and Analytics are fully in the customer's domain.  They may or may not want us to have access to it.  By having separate Firebase project for each customer, we are still managing app-specific vs. customer-specific functionality under one project.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/overview

Comment: @DougStevenson this link is great but there is still a problem.  I can fully expect our customer to create their own Firebase project where they will have the ultimate control of assigning roles.  When they do that, they could assign us a Product-category or Product-level role which is great.  But they own the project which means they have full access to all roles.  What I need is to restrict them altogether from being able to control Remote Config at all.  How do I accomplish that?